# Python Request Libary Error 404 Handling Soundcloud API

Tags: python, request, http-status-code-404, soundcloud

So I'm attempting to create a program that takes the genre and location of recently uploaded Soundcloud tracks and displays them on a map. I'm trying to gather the data using the Soundcloud API however at random points while the program is executing an HTTPError gets thrown. Here's my code:

```
import soundcloud
import urllib2

client = soundcloud.Client(client_id="xxxxx",
                       client_secret="xxxxx",
                       username="xxxx",
                       password="xxxx")

def main():
        for trackId in getAllTrackId('tracks/'):
            try:
                trackId = str(trackId)
                userId = str(client.get('tracks/' + trackId).user_id)
                genre = client.get('tracks/' + trackId).genre
                country = client.get('users/' + userId).country
                city = client.get('users/' + userId).city
                user = client.get('tracks/' + trackId).user
            except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                print e.geturl()
            if (type(city) != None) & (type(country) != None) & (type(genre) != None):
                try:
                    print 'User: ' + userId + '\t\tLocation: ' + city + ', ' + country + '\t\tGenre: ' + genre
                except:
                    print trackId

def getAllTrackId(path):
    items=[]
    page_size=200
    offset=0

    page = client.get(path, limit=page_size, offset=offset)
    #while (len(page) != 0):
    while (offset<=1000):
        for item in page:
            items.append(item.id)
        offset += page_size
        page = client.get(path, limit=page_size, offset=offset)

    return items

main()
```

I'm trying to figure out how to catch the error but also why it is thrown in the first place. I'm new to programming so I'm sure there are many errors in my code but if anyone could help me through this it would be awesome :)

```
(env)xxxxxxx-MacBook-Pro-2:soundcloudmap xxxxxxxxxx$ python soundcloudmap.py
User: 1278531       Location: Detroit, United States        Genre: HSB
User: 1139662       Location: Brasilia, Brazil      Genre: Beat
159333532
User: 23129248      Location: Cadiz, Spain      Genre: Breaks
159333523
User: 10761166      Location: Wadsworth, United States      Genre: Say

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soundcloudmap.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "soundcloudmap.py", line 28, in main
    userId = str(client.get('tracks/' + trackId).user_id)
  File "/Users/michaelspearman/code/soundcloudmap/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 130, in _request
    return wrapped_resource(make_request(method, url, kwargs))
  File "/Users/michaelspearman/code/soundcloudmap/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/request.py", line 134, in make_request
    result.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/michaelspearman/code/soundcloudmap/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 795, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found
```

EDIT:
To catch the error I just need to follow the path of the error correctly.. duhh

```
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
```

should be

```
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
```

However I'm still not sure why it's being thrown..

Answer (score 1):

From the Soundclould Python documentation:

```
tracks = client.get('/tracks', limit=10)
```

compare this to yours:

```
client.get('tracks/' + trackId).user_id
```

More specifically, you are missing the leading `/`. Adding this should work.